# Outgoing Payments API that integrates with Cashapp, Venmo, ACH, etc

Tags: api, online-payment

I'm building a product that involves users getting paid. There are loads of APIs that do the opposite (Stripe, Braintree, Paypal, Square, etc.) - these platforms allow a business to receive money from customers, and have the money wind up in their business bank account.

I'm trying to do the opposite. Primarily I'm interested in taking a user's $Cashtag (Cashapp) or Venmo @handle and sending money from the business's Cashapp/Venmo account directly to the user. I have spent way too much time looking for even how to obtain a Cashapp API key (where are they?!), and it looks like the closest thing that Cashapp's "Network API" has involves issuing "refunds" - that's definitely not right, and probably a violation of the TOS. Venmo's API is shut down entirely. Is there a third party service that can do this? It seems to me like Venmo and Cashapp would want to make it as easy as possible for businesses to send money directly to users' accounts!

There are a few questions on this site that are similar, but none mention the requirement to go directly to Cashapp, Venmo, or a similar P2P wallet.